# Is there any difference between TCP wrappers' GetStream().Read/Write and Socket's Receive/Send

Tags: sockets, .net-core, socketasynceventargs

If client `Socket` is defined like this:

```
args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
args.AcceptSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
await args.AcceptSocket.ConnectAsync(host, port);
```

and server lets it get connected in this way:

```
server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, port));
server.Listen(0);
var arg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
arg.AcceptSocket = await server.AcceptAsync();
```

Are the `byte[]` used in `Send/SendAsync` and `Receive/ReceiveAsync` for transmission between server and client exact equivalent to `NetworkStream`, which we get by calling `tcpClient.GetStream()` for reading/writing, of `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`?

I'm not sure BUT I think they are because `SocketType` for both client and server is set to `Stream` and there shouldn't be any data loss in `send/receive` between those `Streaming` protocols!

Comment: `SocketType.Stream` has nothing to do with `System.IO.Stream` or `GetSteam()`. It's so-named because that's what it's called in the original BSD Sockets (see `SOCK_STREAM` here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html )

Comment: @Dai, is it related to `System.IO.Stream`? it's `tcpClient.GetStream().read()/write()`!

Comment: No, it is **not** related.

Comment: @Dai, are `socket.Send()/Receive()` and `tcpclient.GetStream().Read()/Write()` same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is one of API design.

The .NET `Socket` class is an OOP API for [Win32's Winsock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/getting-started-with-winsock), which itself is derived from [BSD Sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html).

The `Socket` API is built around its own functions for sending and receiving data, with functions like `send`, `recv`. On many platforms you can use the OS-provided filesystem API for reading and writing to sockets the same way you can read and write to local files.

In .NET, the `Stream` class exists as an abstraction of any source or sink for binary data which can be read in a blocking or non-blocking (`async`) manner regardless of where it came from (a file on a local disk, a file on a network share, a buffer in-memory, a TCP connection, a UDP connection, and so on). Read more about `Stream` and its use as an abstraction here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/

The point is that if you write a program or library that processes data - then rather than having to repeat your code over-and-over for different types of IO (files, in-memory buffers, TCP connections, etc) you only need to write your code once using `Stream` and then magically your code can be used in many new places without much work.

[But this comes with a downside of leaky-abstractions](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/). We've since learned over the past 20-30 years of software-engineering that a single interface will not be perfect in every role - for example, a `MemoryStream` is always non-blocking and doesn't need flushing - but a `NetworkStream` (a `Stream` API for `Socket`) behaves very differently despite sharing the same API (remember: interfaces do not describe behavior!), such as how it buffers data internally (e.g. Nagle's algorithm). [This is why .NET is now moving away from `Stream` and towards the new `Pipeline` API model](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/).

So, in short:

- Network connections are **always** using a `Socket` internally.
- The `TcpClient` object adapts the `Socket` API to the `Stream` API (as `NetworkStream`).

  - So a `TcpClient` cannot exist without a `Socket`.
  - And a `NetworkStream` is simply [an adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for `Socket` for the `Stream` API.
- If your program does not need to abstract-away IO using the `Stream` API then you should only use the `Socket` API and not use `NetworkStream` or `TcpClient`.
- If you do need to pass network data around using a `Stream` model, then use `TcpClient` and `NetworkStream` - but be-aware of how `NetworkStream` behaves and you should always use non-blocking (async, aka "overlapped IO") to avoid bottlenecks and program freezes.

Comment: and behind the scene `TcpClient`'s `GetStream().Read/Write` is calling `Socket`'s `Receive/Send`, right?

Comment: @EmonHaque Correct.